# Pivot and Sum in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a following tables

table1

```
id name
1  A
3  B
```

table2

```
id label   value
1   tag     a
1   tag     b
1   time    10
1   time    20
1   score   20
2   tag     a
2   time    30
2   score   40 
3   tag     b 
3   time    50
3   time    55
3   score   60
```

first I'd like to join table2 as follows

```
select *
from table1 left join on table2 using(id)
where label in ('tag')
```

```
id name tag
1   A   a
1   A   b
3   B   b
```

and then join table2 with `id` and pivot and sum up them

```
id name tag time score
1   A   a   10    20
1   A   b   10    20
3   B   b   50    60
```

I guess it is very complicated, are there any way to achieve this?

In Redshift it seems that there is no way to pivot them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a pivot query.  I think this does what you are looking for:

```
create table table1 (id int, name varchar(16));
insert into table1 values
(1, 'A'),
(3, 'B')
;

create table table2 (id int, label varchar(16), value varchar(16));
insert into table2 values 
(1,   'tag', 'a'),
(1,   'tag', 'b'),
(1,   'time', '10'),
(1,   'score', '20'),
(2,   'tag', 'a'),
(2,   'time', '30'),
(2,   'score', '40'),
(3,   'tag', 'b'), 
(3,   'time', '50'),
(3,   'score', '60')
;

select t2.id, a.name, a.tag_value, sum(decode(label, 'time', value::int)) as total_time, sum(decode(label, 'score', value::int)) as total_score
from table2 t2
join (
    select id, name, value as tag_value
    from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 using(id)
    where t2.label in ('tag')
    ) a
on t2.id = a.id 
group by 1, 2, 3
order by 1, 2, 3
;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer,I could try them. when I see my data,`table2` `time`label is duplicated. I'd like to join min(value) to table 1, are there any change to provided query ? I changed my question,, sorry for inconvenience. thanks

Comment: Just change "sum" to "min" in the outer select for the total_time result.  I did have questions about your data since in table2 you have tag "a" and tag "b" for id "1" and it looks like each of these tags has time and score values - does your data model need to be updated to know which time and score values go with which tag value?